# Symfony2 "FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class" from time to time

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fatal-error

today I got an very odd situation. I am implementing a simple 1:m relation between two entites in Doctrine Symfony2.

There are Users and Groups. Each User should be added to exactly one Group.

But every 3-4 reload my controller spits out an error.

```
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Proxies\__CG__\Creativebrains\AthleteBundle\Entity\Group in /var/www/symfony2/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__CreativebrainsAthleteBundleEntityGroup.php line 8
```

And a reload later I get the normal JSON output

```
{
    id: 1,
    username: "dominik",
    email: "dominik@creativebrains.net",
    enabled: true,
    displayname: "Dominik",
    group: {
        name: "asd"
        ...
    }
}
```

I think it is some sort of caching error but I cannot understand why.

Hopefully some one knows an answer.
Have a nice day!

Comment: Nuke your cache: `rm -rf app/cache/*` from the project root.

Comment: Hi, thank you but I already tried it several times. I now have a theorie that it is Vagrant/NFS which does the damage. When I moved the cache folder to /tmp/ it seems to work. I will look further into it and keep you updated. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes, I've also experienced problems using vagrant/nfs on my MacBook. I have to nuke the cache with `rm -rf` and then run `php app/console cache:clear -e=prod -n` FROM THE VAGRANT BOX. lol I have to stress that because running it from a local terminal does strange things. I think I also had to set the umask to 0000 in AppKernel and console.

Comment: I have also been plagued with this error. I'm not using anything weird like Vagrant or NFS just nginx + php-fpm. I have traced the problem to APC. It seems anytime two simultaneous requests there is some sort of race condition creating these cache files. Whenever it happens I restart php-fpm and all is well. Not sure how we can fix it but turning off APC prevents it from happening.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to APC opcode cache. I've been experiencing it just as you described, it seems to happen most with multiple simultaneous requests. Disabling APC solves the problem but it's not ideal. You can disable it just for these generated proxies by adding this to your php.ini file:

`apc.filters = '-.*__CG__.*'`

This solved the problem for me. It was only ever an issue in the dev environment so it shouldn't be used on production.